# Which Antoine de Saint Exupery quote is correct?

Tags: citations

Is it:

> La perfection est atteinte non quand il ne reste rien à ajouter, mais quand il ne reste rien à enlever.

or:

> La perfection est atteinte, non pas lorsqu'il n'y a plus rien à ajouter, mais lorsqu'il n'y a plus rien à retirer.

?

Comment: What did you try, to start searching ? (Where is it from?) What about different versions of the same ideas, both written by him ? (Does it really matter ?) Voting "too localized".

Answer (score 12):

According to the original text, the exact quote is:

> Il semble que la perfection soit atteinte non quand il n’y a plus rien
>   à ajouter, mais quand il n’y a plus rien à retrancher.

Source: https://biblio.wiki/wiki/Terre_des_hommes/III (Works by this author are in the public domain in countries where the copyright term is the author's life plus 67 years or less.)